# LocalStorage is getting [object Object]

Tags: javascript

I am trying to retrieve the data stored in local storage but I get the value as `[object Object]`. I know that local storage only takes strings and the data has to be `JSON.stringify` when setting and `JSON.parse` when getting but I still get it as `[object Object]`.

Instead of `[object Object]` I want to display the value entered in the input field

I am trying to get a list of items on button click. To do this I am saving the value entered in the input field and pushing it to an array.

I have created an empty array like
`var todosArr = Array();`

when a value is entered in the input field and the submit button is clicked, this is the code executed

```
todosArr.push({"listname":todoTxtField.value});
localStorage.setItem('todos', JSON.stringify(todosArr));
```

and to display the listing in the span this is the code written

`listSpan.innerText = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('todos'));`

Comment: Hi. When you `console.log(JSON.stringify(todosArr))` what do you get?

Comment: You're setting `innerText` of that element to the JSON _you've parsed_ which is why you're getting [object Object] - because it's now an object. What output in that text do you want? You should update your question.

Comment: This is what I get. I `[{"listname":"list 1"}]`

Comment: @Andy I want it to display the value entered in the input field. for eg if I write "new listing", this should be shown

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For displaying first element in array:

```
var arr = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('todos'))
listSpan.innerText = arr[0].listname;
```

or for all elements in array:

```
arr.forEach(o => {
  listSpan.innerText += o.listname
})
```

Comment: But this will only show the first element in an array right? What should I do if I want to list elements every time the button is clicked?

Comment: Thank you!.. This worked perfectly....but please explain why I was getting [object Object] when I was setting json.parse with inner text

Comment: `[object Object]` is a string version of an object instance, and you have array of objects